# I am using Javafx and I am trying to manipulate code within a .css file but cannot

Tags: java, css, javafx, filewriter, file-writing

The problem with my code is that I wish to change the string assigned to defaultImg so that it will change the background image of the application. I do not receive a runtime or compile error when running the application. The "client.css" file is not being updated. What am I messing up? There are buttons called "img1" - "img6". These are located near the bottom of my code. In these methods I open a file writer to clear and rewrite the code within the css document. Thank you in advance for helping me out.

```
  //settings Application:

    S_windowPane = new GridPane();
    S_windowPane.setPadding(new Insets(35));
    S_windowPane.setHgap(0);
    S_windowPane.setVgap(0);
    S_windowPane.setId("SettingsPane");

    S_buttonPane = new GridPane();
    S_buttonPane.setPadding(new Insets(15));
    S_buttonPane.setHgap(0);
    S_buttonPane.setVgap(20);
    S_buttonPane.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    S_buttonPane.setId("buttonPane");

    S_BkgrndImagePane = new GridPane();
    S_BkgrndImagePane.setPrefWidth(500);
    S_BkgrndImagePane.setPrefHeight(300);
    S_BkgrndImagePane.setHgap(10);
    S_BkgrndImagePane.setVgap(20);
    S_BkgrndImagePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    S_BkgrndImagePane.setId("BackgroundImagePane");

    Image img1_ = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/backgroundImg1.jpg"));
    img1 = new Button();
    img1.setGraphic(new ImageView(img1_));
    S_BkgrndImagePane.add(img1, 0, 0);

    Image img2_ = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/backgroundImg2.jpg"));
    img2 = new Button();
    img2.setGraphic(new ImageView(img2_));
    S_BkgrndImagePane.add(img2, 1, 0);

    Image img3_ = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/backgroundImg3.jpg"));
    img3 = new Button();
    img3.setGraphic(new ImageView(img3_));
    S_BkgrndImagePane.add(img3, 2, 0);

    Image img4_ = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/backgroundImg4.jpg"));
    img4 = new Button();
    img4.setGraphic(new ImageView(img4_));
    S_BkgrndImagePane.add(img4, 0, 1);

    Image img5_ = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/backgroundImg5.jpg"));
    img5 = new Button();
    img5.setGraphic(new ImageView(img5_));
    S_BkgrndImagePane.add(img5, 1, 1);

    Image img6_ = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/backgroundImg6.jpg"));
    img6 = new Button();
    img6.setGraphic(new ImageView(img6_));
    S_BkgrndImagePane.add(img6, 2, 1);



    cancel = new Button();
    cancel.setText("cancel");
    cancel.setPrefWidth(70);
    cancel.setPrefHeight(35);
    S_buttonPane.add(cancel, 0, 0);
    cancel.setId("cancel");

    apply = new Button();
    apply.setText("apply");
    apply.setPrefWidth(70);
    apply.setPrefHeight(35);
    S_buttonPane.add(apply, 0, 1);
    apply.setId("apply");

    S_windowPane.add(S_BkgrndImagePane, 0, 0);
    S_windowPane.add(S_buttonPane, 1, 0);

    S_root = new StackPane();
    S_root.setId("S_root");

    S_root.getChildren().add(S_windowPane);
    settingsScene = new Scene(S_root, 670,420);
    settingsScene.getStylesheets().add("client.css");


    cancel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            primaryStage.setScene(clientScene);
        }
    });


    //used to reset and apply changes
    apply.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {

            primaryStage.close();
            primaryStage.setScene(settingsScene);
            primaryStage.show();
            primaryStage.close();
            primaryStage.setScene(settingsScene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
    });

//leaves settings menu without making physical changes
    cancel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            primaryStage.setScene(clientScene);
        }
    });



    img1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println(1);
            try {
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                pw = new PrintWriter("src/client.css");
//long string containing code needed for .css
                pw.write("#C_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/background.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#S_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/background.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#IPinput{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}.button{-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #d6d6d6),linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 0%, #d9d9d9 20%, #d6d6d6 100%),linear-gradient(#dddddd 0%, #f6f6f6 50%);-fx-background-radius: 8,7,6;-fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;-fx-text-fill: black;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#textDisplay{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );-fx-font-fill: black;}#BackgroundImagePane{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#input{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}");
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



    img2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println(2);
            try {
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                pw = new PrintWriter("src/client.css");
//long string containing code needed for .css
                pw.write("#C_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/BackGround2.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#S_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/BackGround2.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#IPinput{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}.button{-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #d6d6d6),linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 0%, #d9d9d9 20%, #d6d6d6 100%),linear-gradient(#dddddd 0%, #f6f6f6 50%);-fx-background-radius: 8,7,6;-fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;-fx-text-fill: black;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#textDisplay{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );-fx-font-fill: black;}#BackgroundImagePane{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#input{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}");
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



    img3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println(3);
            try {
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                pw = new PrintWriter("src/client.css");
//long string containing code needed for .css
                pw.write("#C_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/BackGround3.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#S_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/BackGround3.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#IPinput{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}.button{-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #d6d6d6),linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 0%, #d9d9d9 20%, #d6d6d6 100%),linear-gradient(#dddddd 0%, #f6f6f6 50%);-fx-background-radius: 8,7,6;-fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;-fx-text-fill: black;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#textDisplay{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );-fx-font-fill: black;}#BackgroundImagePane{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#input{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}");
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



    img4.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println(4);
            try {
                PrintWriter pw = null;
//long string containing code needed for .css
                pw = new PrintWriter("src/client.css");
                pw.write("#C_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/BackGround4.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#S_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/BackGround4.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#IPinput{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}.button{-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #d6d6d6),linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 0%, #d9d9d9 20%, #d6d6d6 100%),linear-gradient(#dddddd 0%, #f6f6f6 50%);-fx-background-radius: 8,7,6;-fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;-fx-text-fill: black;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#textDisplay{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );-fx-font-fill: black;}#BackgroundImagePane{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#input{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}");
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



    img5.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println(5);
            try {
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                pw = new PrintWriter("src/client.css");
//long string containing code needed for .css
                pw.write("#C_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/BackGround5.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#S_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/BackGround5.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#IPinput{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}.button{-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #d6d6d6),linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 0%, #d9d9d9 20%, #d6d6d6 100%),linear-gradient(#dddddd 0%, #f6f6f6 50%);-fx-background-radius: 8,7,6;-fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;-fx-text-fill: black;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#textDisplay{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );-fx-font-fill: black;}#BackgroundImagePane{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#input{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}");
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



    img6.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println(6);
            try {
//long string containing code needed for .css
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                pw = new PrintWriter("src/client.css");
                pw.write("#C_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/BackGround6.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#S_root{-fx-background-image: url('images/BackGround6.jpg');-fx-background-repeat: repeat;}#IPinput{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}.button{-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #d6d6d6),linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 0%, #d9d9d9 20%, #d6d6d6 100%),linear-gradient(#dddddd 0%, #f6f6f6 50%);-fx-background-radius: 8,7,6;-fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;-fx-text-fill: black;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#textDisplay{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );-fx-font-fill: black;}#BackgroundImagePane{-fx-opacity: 1.0;-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}#input{-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );}");
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please update your question so it's a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: a) Stylesheets are not refreshed magically. Writing new contents to the file does not refresh the CSS style that javafx has read from the file before. b) `defaulted` is only assigned once. Since it's a instance field initialized in the declaration, the RHS is evaluated once at object creation. At this time `defaultImg` is `null`. Modifying `defaultImg` does not change `defaulted`.

Comment: To emphasize zyexal’s point:  659 lines of code is *too much.*  Few if any Stack Overflow readers are going to wade through all that;  for most of us, our time is valuable.  Trim it down to just the parts that are relevant to your question:  The lines that make use of `client.css` and the lines that write to `client.css`.

Comment: Nevermind, I changed a portion of my code so that it will not use "defaulted"  but the revised string itself so that it would update the file correctly. On top of that I went to **window>preferences>workspace** and enabled refresh using native hooks or polling. After that I wrote a method to close and reopen the scene. Voila it works now.